# CUDA or thrust: getting n maximum numbers in a grouped array

Tags: cuda, thrust

I divide an array into n groups, each group has equal size, I want to get the n maximum numbers in each group.

For example:[image]

I calculate the groupID for each thread and use atomicMax on a global array. So when the group number is small, the performance is poor. Seems `thrust::reduce_by_key` can do this, but I haven't figure out yet.

Any better ideas?

Comment: `reduce_by_key` can do it.  Are you asking how to do it with `reduce_by_key` ?

Comment: @RobertCrovella  yes, `reduce_by_key` can do it, but I think `reduce_by_key` may sort the keys first, which in my case is unnecessary, for the keys in my case is consecutive. I only know I can use atomicMax for each group to get the max number for now, there must have faster way to do it. Could you give me some tips?

Comment: `reduce_by_key` doesn't sort anything.  The keys that you pass to reduce_by_key must already be grouped.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One possible approach is to use [thrust::reduce_by_key](https://thrust.github.io/doc/group__reductions.html#ga633d78d4cb2650624ec354c9abd0c97f).  At least with respect to thrust, I don't think there would be a better way to do it.

Here's a worked example:

```
$ cat t663.cu
#include <iostream>
#include <thrust/reduce.h>
#include <thrust/device_vector.h>
#include <thrust/copy.h>
#include <thrust/functional.h>
#include <thrust/iterator/transform_iterator.h>
#include <thrust/iterator/counting_iterator.h>
#include <thrust/fill.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define N_GROUPS 4
#define GRP_SIZE 4
#define nTPB 256
#define DSIZE (N_GROUPS * GRP_SIZE)
#define SCALE_MOD 1024
#include <time.h>
#include <sys/time.h>

unsigned long long dtime_usec(unsigned long long prev){
#define USECPSEC 1000000ULL
  timeval tv1;
  gettimeofday(&tv1,0);
  return ((tv1.tv_sec * USECPSEC)+tv1.tv_usec) - prev;
}

template <typename T>
__global__ void max_kernel(const T *data, T *result, const int num_groups, const int group_size){

  int idx = threadIdx.x+blockDim.x*blockIdx.x;

  if (idx < (num_groups*group_size))
    atomicMax(result + (idx/group_size), data[idx]);
}


struct idx_fctr : public thrust::unary_function<int, int>
{
  int mod;
  idx_fctr(const int _mod) : mod(_mod) {} ;
  __host__ __device__ int operator()(const int &val) const {
    return val/mod;
  }
};

template <typename T>
struct max_fctr : public thrust::binary_function<T, T, T>
{
  __host__ __device__ T operator()(const T &val1, const T &val2) const {
  return (val1>val2)?val1:val2;
  }
};

int main(int argc, char *argv[]){
  int grp_size = GRP_SIZE;
  int n_groups = N_GROUPS;
  if (argc > 2){
    grp_size = atoi(argv[1]);
    n_groups = atoi(argv[2]);}

  int *data;
  int dsize = grp_size*n_groups;
  data = new int[dsize];

  for (int i = 0; i < dsize; i++) data[i] = rand()%SCALE_MOD;
  thrust::device_vector<int> d_data(data, data+dsize);
  thrust::device_vector<int> d_keys_out(n_groups);
  thrust::device_vector<int> d_vals_out(n_groups);

  unsigned long long dtime = dtime_usec(0);
  thrust::reduce_by_key(thrust::make_transform_iterator(thrust::make_counting_iterator(0), idx_fctr(grp_size)), thrust::make_transform_iterator(thrust::make_counting_iterator(dsize), idx_fctr(grp_size)), d_data.begin(), d_keys_out.begin(), d_vals_out.begin(), thrust::equal_to<int>(), max_fctr<int>());
  cudaDeviceSynchronize();
  dtime = dtime_usec(dtime);
  std::cout << "thrust time: " << dtime/(float)USECPSEC << std::endl;
#ifdef DEBUG_PRINT
  std::cout << "data: " << std::endl;
  thrust::copy(d_data.begin(), d_data.end(), std::ostream_iterator<int>(std::cout, ","));
  std::cout << std::endl << "keys: " << std::endl;
  thrust::copy(d_keys_out.begin(), d_keys_out.end(), std::ostream_iterator<int>(std::cout, ","));
  std::cout << std::endl << "maxima: " << std::endl;
  thrust::copy(d_vals_out.begin(), d_vals_out.end(), std::ostream_iterator<int>(std::cout, ","));
  std::cout << std::endl;
#endif

  thrust::fill(d_vals_out.begin(), d_vals_out.end(), 0);
  dtime = dtime_usec(0);
  max_kernel<<<(dsize+nTPB-1)/nTPB, nTPB>>>(thrust::raw_pointer_cast(d_data.data()), thrust::raw_pointer_cast(d_vals_out.data()), n_groups, grp_size);
  cudaDeviceSynchronize();
  dtime = dtime_usec(dtime);
  std::cout << "kernel time: " << dtime/(float)USECPSEC << std::endl;
#ifdef DEBUG_PRINT
  std::cout << "data: " << std::endl;
  thrust::copy(d_data.begin(), d_data.end(), std::ostream_iterator<int>(std::cout, ","));
  std::cout << std::endl << "keys: " << std::endl;
  thrust::copy(d_keys_out.begin(), d_keys_out.end(), std::ostream_iterator<int>(std::cout, ","));
  std::cout << std::endl << "maxima: " << std::endl;
  thrust::copy(d_vals_out.begin(), d_vals_out.end(), std::ostream_iterator<int>(std::cout, ","));
  std::cout << std::endl;
#endif

  return 0;
}  


$ nvcc -arch=sm_20 -o t663 t663.cu
$ ./t663
data:
359,966,105,115,81,255,74,236,809,205,186,939,498,763,483,326,
keys:
0,1,2,3,
maxima:
966,255,939,763,
$
```

The method I am showing above automatically generates the group keys, on the fly.

**EDIT:** I've modified the code to be a benchmarkable comparison between a naive atomicMax kernel and the thrust::reduce_by_key method. For large data sets, thrust seems to do better.  For small data sets, especially when the group size is small, the kernel seems to do better.  Performance varies by dimensions (which can be passed on the command line) and gpu type.  To run with varying data set sizes, pass the group size as the first command line parameter, and the number of groups as the second.  In general for small group sizes, the kernel method seems to do better.  For larger group sizes, the thrust method seems to do better.

when I run the code with a group size of 1024 and number of groups equal to 100000, the thrust code runs in about 0.03 seconds on a K40c, and the kernel method takes about 4x longer.  If I reduce the group size to 4, the kernel method becomes about 30x faster than the thrust method.  The ratios and breakpoints will definitely vary by GPU type.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I should have read the description of `reduce_by_key` more carefully, indeed the keys must be grouped before using `reduce_by_key`. I was mislead by an example.

Comment: I tried `reduce_by_key`, but the performance is worse than directly use atomicMax on global memory. This is weird, I added `thrust::cuda::par( thrustCachedAllocator )`, and performance is better than before but still worse than atomicMax.

Comment: Yes, I agree performance varies based on exact size of data set and group size, as well as GPU type.  You haven't indicated any of these things.  I've updated the code to provide a benchmarkable comparison.